# Numpy broadcasting inequality operator

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

Numpy broadcasting question.  I have two arrays similar to these:

```
>my_array = np.array([[3,1,2,0] , [4,5,2,1]])
>my_array
array([[3, 1, 2, 0],
       [4, 5, 2, 1]])



>second_array = np.array([2,5])

>second_array
array([2, 5])
```

What I want to do is transpose second_array and test, by column, to see if my_array is >= second_array .  So the result would be like this:

```
>final_array = np.array([ [ (3 >= 2), (1>= 2), (2>=2), (0>=2)] , [(4 >=5),(5>=5),(2>=5),(1>=5)]])
>final_array

array([[ True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

I'm pretty new to matrix operations in Numpy (been doing them in R for a long  time) so thanks for helping with such an introductory question.

Comment: `my_array >= second_array[:, None]`

Comment: First is (2,5), second (2,).  To compare on the 2 dimension, make the second (2,1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to reshape `second_array` so that it has appropriate dimensions:

```
my_array >= second_array.reshape(2,1) # or (-1,1) if height is unknown
```

Or equivalently:

```
my_array >= second_array[:,np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Appreciate the comment about the unknown height - in reality the height of second_array is going to change each iteration